# Public Game Server IP and Ports

Tags: php, status

I'm trying to make a Server Status Checker for an online MMO that I play. It is not a private server, and I do not personally own/control the game. I already have the needed Php coding to do what I want, but I still need the proper IP for the game, and the ports it uses. I would be happy just getting the port for the Login server, but getting the port for the game server would be nice too.
I have tried starting up the game and entering *netstat -bn* in the command promt, but the returned values don't seem to work. Just to be safe, I have included my code below for my status checker page, just in case it is due to my coding.

```
<?php
$ip = "###.###.###.###";
$onlinetext = "Online" ;
$offlinetext = "Offline" ;
$port = "####";

if(@fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1)) {
echo"<img src='sonline.png' width='20' height='20' border='0'> $onlinetext";
} else {
echo"<img src='soffline.png' width='20' height='20' border='0'> $offlinetext";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're setting timeout to 1 second only, try to set it to 15 for example

Comment: I tried changing the timeout like suggested, but all the IP and ports have tried still return as offline even though I know for a fact it is online right now.

Comment: check ip and ports with telnet